# BigQuery- how to use slots for my queries

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, slot, on-demand-resources

I am trying to use slots to run my queries, so I asked from BigQuery to increase my quota after my request got approval (5 days!) I pressed on "buy slots" and select 400 (i have 500 available) and I thought that will be enough to make sure that my queries will run on those 400 slots and not on the "on-demand-serverless" method.
unfortunately, I got the bill for my queries the day after and I saw they charged me for the "on-demand" charging method.
I tried to use BigQuery chat support to understand how to use those 400 slots and guarantee that my queries will run on those slots but I didn't get any useful answer!

does someone know how can I use those slots to run my query? what I did wrong?
thanks,

Answer (score 1):

After you buy BigQuery slots you have to create a "reservation" and assigned it to a project. At that point, all the queries running inside that project (note that they can reference table outside the project) will use that slots reservation. See [Assign a project to a reservation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reservations-tasks#assign_my_prod_project_to_prod_reservation) for more details.